# How to change image location

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm developing WPF with C# and I have this code to get the picture `angry.png` from the `smiles` folder in the output folder (e.g. `bin\debug`):

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage(
    new Uri(@"smiles/angry.png",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

But I want to get the picture `angry.png` from another location like `Resources\Image\smiles\angry.png`. Could you tell me how to change the folder location so that this would work?

Comment: Try using `..\..\Resources\Image\smiles\angry.png` - if it works I'll add an answer and explain.

Comment: What is the relation between Resources and the bin folder?

Answer (score 1):

In that case `..\..\Resources\Image\smiles\angry.png` should be sufficient.

Comment: I already try with your code, but it still doesn't work. any more solution?